# discord.py how takes 1 values per user

Tags: discord.py

**problem**: i want a command that is capable to takes more than one user
like

1 place congrats juan

2 place congrast dolores

3...

obviously if they answered it correctly
i have a command but it only takes the first correct value it would be nice if you can help me

````
@bot.command()
async def rev(ctx):
    a = "liechtenstein" #this is just an example
    b = a[::-1]
    await ctx.send(a)
    def check(msg: discord.Message) -> True:
        return msg.content == b and msg.channel == ctx.message.channel
    try:
        guess = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=7, check=check)
        await ctx.send(f"congrats {guess.author}")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("ups time over")```
````

the problem is when the answer is correct it break, but i want others users continue sendings messages
how can i change it to

Answer (score 0):

`guess = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=7, check=check)` 
`await ctx.send("Now Next One")` 
`guess2 = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=7, check=check)` 
`await ctx.send("Now Next One")` 
**....**

`await ctx.send(f"congrats {guess.author}")`

Something Like This !